# Compare CSV files and return duplicates to a new CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that runs everyday and outputs a CSV file with a bunch of lines.

**Example:**
CSV Today:

```
Access Point,MacAddress,Status,Site,Date
AP03 - 1695,5c5b352e3c9b,Disconnected,Store 1695,08-21-2019
AP01 - 0099,5c5b352e44b1,Disconnected,Store 0099,08-21-2019
AP07 - 1961,5c5b350eeae9,Disconnected,Store 1961,08-21-2019
AP05 - 3165,5c5b352e1f04,Disconnected,Store 3165,08-21-2019
AP02 - 1161,5c5b352e4484,Disconnected,Store 1161,08-21-2019
AP05 - 0249,5c5b352e40c9,Disconnected,Store 0249,08-21-2019
AP06 - 1057,5c5b352e1ed7,Disconnected,Store 1057,08-21-2019
AP01 - 2700,5c5b353e444d,Disconnected,Store 2700,08-21-2019
AP02 - 2700,5c5b352ea519,Disconnected,Store 2700,08-21-2019
AP02 - 2722,5c5b352eb446,Disconnected,Store 2722,08-21-2019
```

CSV Yesterday:

```
Access Point,MacAddress,Status,Site,Date
AP03 - 1695,5c5b352e3c9b,Disconnected,Store 1695,08-20-2019
AP01 - 0099,5c5b352e44b1,Disconnected,Store 0099,08-20-2019
AP07 - 1961,5c5b350eeae9,Disconnected,Store 1961,08-20-2019
AP05 - 3165,5c5b352e1f04,Disconnected,Store 3165,08-20-2019
AP02 - 1161,5c5b352e4484,Disconnected,Store 1161,08-20-2019
AP05 - 0249,5c5b352e40c9,Disconnected,Store 0249,08-20-2019
AP06 - 1057,5c5b352e1ed7,Disconnected,Store 1057,08-20-2019
AP01 - 2700,5c5b353e444d,Disconnected,Store 2700,08-20-2019
AP02 - 2700,5c5b352ea519,Disconnected,Store 2700,08-20-2019
AP06 - 0415,5c5b352ebdce,Disconnected,Store 0415,08-20-2019
AP03 - 2542,5c5b353e3e94,Disconnected,Store 2542,08-20-2019
AP03 - 0788,5c5b353e1216,Disconnected,Store 0788,08-20-2019
AP04 - 0788,5c5b353e11e9,Disconnected,Store 0788,08-20-2019
AP05 - 0788,5c5b353e122a,Disconnected,Store 0788,08-20-2019
AP06 - 0788,5c5b353e1220,Disconnected,Store 0788,08-20-2019
AP01 - 1366,5c5b353e136a,Disconnected,Store 1366,08-20-2019
AP05 - 0671,5c5b352eb7ed,Disconnected,Store 0671,08-20-2019
```

I am trying to get a script written that compares todays generated file, with yesterdays, then returns ONLY duplicates into a new CSV file.(if possible, compare only the MacAddress section, that way the date wont throw everything off from the last column)

I have found dozens and dozens of articles and questions similar to this, but the majority of them are doing the opposite (removing duplicates) and I cannot get them to work for 1 reason or another.

Can someone point me into the right direction please?

**Desired Output (something similar):**

```
Access Point,MacAddress,Status,Site,Date
AP03 - 1695,5c5b352e3c9b,Disconnected,Store 1695,08-21-2019
AP01 - 0099,5c5b352e44b1,Disconnected,Store 0099,08-21-2019
AP07 - 1961,5c5b350eeae9,Disconnected,Store 1961,08-21-2019
AP05 - 3165,5c5b352e1f04,Disconnected,Store 3165,08-21-2019
AP06 - 1057,5c5b352e1ed7,Disconnected,Store 1057,08-21-2019
AP01 - 2700,5c5b353e444d,Disconnected,Store 2700,08-21-2019
AP02 - 2700,5c5b352ea519,Disconnected,Store 2700,08-21-2019
```

I have tried so many variations to get this working, I just have a bare-bones script at the moment for this task, as I am not sure whats the best method to even start with.

**Current:**

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from datetime import date, timedelta

# Setting Dates
today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)
# Setting files with Dates
currentFile = "ap-inventory_" + today.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') + ".csv"
yesterdayFile = "ap-inventory_" + yesterday.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') + ".csv"
```

This was the furthest I got, however I could never get it to correctly compare the results

```
import csv
from datetime import date, timedelta

# Setting Dates
today = date.today()
yesterday = today - timedelta(days = 1)
# Setting files with Dates
currentFile = "ap-inventory_" + today.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') + ".csv"
yesterdayFile = "ap-inventory_" + yesterday.strftime('%m-%d-%Y') + ".csv"


with open('master.csv', 'rt') as master:
    master_indices = dict((r[1], i) for i, r in enumerate(csv.reader(master)))

with open(currentFile, 'rt') as hosts:
    with open(yesterdayFile, 'wt') as results:
        reader = csv.reader(hosts)
        writer = csv.writer(results)

        writer.writerow(next(reader, []) + ['RESULTS'])

        for row in reader:
            index = master_indices.get(row[3])
            if index is not None:
                message = 'FOUND in master list (row {})'.format(index)
            else:
                message = 'NOT FOUND in master list'
            writer.writerow(row + [message])
```

Comment: Please an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your script so we can fix it to do what you want rather than us writing an entirely new script that you can't use because it doesn't follow the same format of your current script.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh I have tried so many different variations to get this working, everything from just using the CSV library to using Pandas. I am currently back to step one as I do not know the best method to even start with.

Comment: Just a fyi. Unless you post a script or something we can work with most people will overlook this. You can't expect us to put in more work in your answer than what you give in your question. Post the one that got you the closest to what you wanted.

Comment: @EdekiOkoh I posted the bare-bones, but nothing to it. I understand where you are coming from tho. Let me back-date my project to give you(and others) more to work from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without pandas, you can use something like:

```
import time
with open("yesterday.csv") as f1, open("today.csv") as f2, open("output.csv", "w+") as out:

    yesterday = []
    for line in list(f1)[1:]:
        yesterday.append(",".join(line.split(",")[:-1]))

    today = []
    for line in list(f2)[1:]:
        today.append(",".join(line.split(",")[:-1]))

    date_today = time.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')
    common = [f"{x},{date_today}" for x in list(set(today) & set(yesterday))]
    header = "Access Point,MacAddress,Status,Site,Date"
    out.write(f"{header}\n")
    for o in common:
        out.write(f"{o}\n")
```

---

The *desired output (something similiar)* is:

```
Access Point,MacAddress,Status,Site,Date
AP05 - 3165,5c5b352e1f04,Disconnected,Store 3165,08-21-2019
AP07 - 1961,5c5b350eeae9,Disconnected,Store 1961,08-21-2019
AP02 - 1161,5c5b352e4484,Disconnected,Store 1161,08-21-2019
AP03 - 1695,5c5b352e3c9b,Disconnected,Store 1695,08-21-2019
AP02 - 2700,5c5b352ea519,Disconnected,Store 2700,08-21-2019
AP05 - 0249,5c5b352e40c9,Disconnected,Store 0249,08-21-2019
AP06 - 1057,5c5b352e1ed7,Disconnected,Store 1057,08-21-2019
AP01 - 0099,5c5b352e44b1,Disconnected,Store 0099,08-21-2019
AP01 - 2700,5c5b353e444d,Disconnected,Store 2700,08-21-2019
```

Which are the common items (without date) between `yesterday.csv` and `today.csv` files.
[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/71d3a10561)

---

Explanation of

```
common = [f"{x},{date_today}" for x in list(set(today) & set(yesterday))]
```

- `f"{var}"` -  is called an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)
- `list(set(today) & set(yesterday)` -  give us the common elements  between lists
- `[x for x in list]` is called a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

Comment: This is perfect - and sooo much easier then using Pandas. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Quick learning question - what is the row with date_today for exactly(I got its to get todays date, and format it, but not sure why we are using it completely). I see its called in the line 'common', but have never seen that syntax being used.

Comment: I've posted a small explanation of  `common = [f"{x},{date_today}" for x in list(set(today) & set(yesterday))]`. I'm sorry for not being able to comment the whole code but time is of essence!

Answer (score 1):

I think, i found a solution using pandas.

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('DataSources/file_today.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('DataSources/file_tomorrow.csv')

df = pd.concat([df1, df2])

df = df.sort_values(['MacAddress','Date'])
new_df = df.drop_duplicates(['MacAddress'], keep ='first')

drop_df = df.merge(new_df, how = 'outer' ,indicator=True).loc[lambda x : x['_merge']=='left_only']

# your result
drop_df
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this with pandas would be along the lines of:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv("your_file_from_yesterday.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("your_file_from_today.csv")

df_combined = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0)

duplicates = df_combined["your_column_of_interest"].duplicated(keep="last")
#keep="first" if you want the addresses from yesterday that were duplicated.
```

duplicates is now a boolean structure that you can use for indexing in the dataframe.

```
df_combined[duplicates]
```

[image]

You can save this as a new file.

```
df_combined[duplicates].to_csv("duplicates_only.csv")
```

docs for [pd.duplicated()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html), [pd.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), [pd.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: The lines aren't equal, the date changes.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about the lines aren't equal, but dates changing shouldn't be an issue if you're looking for duplicates in the MacAddress.  I edited for clarity and demonstrating output.